# Which would you use: full-size, full-sized, full size or full sized?

Tags: word-choice, hyphenation

I want to use *full-sized*, as in:

> Click here to download a full-sized version of this image.

But [Google NGrams disagrees](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=full+size%2Cfull+sized%2Cfull-size%2Cfull-sized&year_start=1800&year_end=3000smoothing=3):

[image: "Full size" wins overwhelmingly, with "full sized" marginally above zero.]

So, given:

1. full-size
2. full-sized
3. full size
4. full sized

which would you employ and why?

Comment: I would first ask myself "has it been sized?" Has it been made that size intentionally, or is it just that size incidentally? We have words like "downsized" that convey intent, and can be an adjective, however "downsize" can only be a verb. Because "of the unambiguity of "-sized" it can be tempting to use, even for things that have not been intentionally "-sized". "Elephant-size portion" sounds like a portion *the size of* an elephant, while "elephant-sized portion" sounds like a portion big enough to be *for* an elephant. Both are correct, but the nuances can differ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Collins Cobuild English Dictionary:

> **full-size or full-sized** A full-size or full-sized model or
>   picture is the same size as the thing
>   or person that it represents.

So, I would choose one of those options and trust the dictionary.

Comment: But this is my issue: what motivates the choice of one over the other, since they're not *really* in free variation? Instinctively, which would use you **first**?

Comment: According to Collins Cobuild they are equal. I would use full-size. While my husband would use full-sized. It comes down to what you think is right.

Answer (score 3):

I really couldn't decide between **full-sized** and **full-size** in your example: both would be perfectly fine and common. Note that you need the hyphen in either case, because it is a compound adjective (an adjective composed of more than one word) and it comes before the noun it belongs to. If you put it after, you don't need the hyphen: *this picture is not full size*. (Note that it is often more stylistically pleasing to use a different construction in that case.)

Comment: Indeed, I always hyphenate this compound but thought to include the others because I have seen them 'in the wild'.

Answer (score 2):

Either option is correct and usable.  Both they have slightly different emphases.  "Full-size" indicates that it is of the right size, while "full-sized" may additionally imply that it was deliberately made to that size.  It's a very slight difference.

@Cerberus is correct that no hyphen is used when you put it afterwards.

Comment: Agreed and this is why I would use *full-size*. However, *full-size* don't imply necessarily the *"right"* size. The extent to which the *"ed"* suffix is acceptable (or even used) depends on the word. For example *right-handed* (not *right-hand*), *transgender* (not *transgendered*, though [debate over this is active](http://tranifesto.com/2013/11/11/ask-matt-why-the-fuss-over-transgendered-and-is-transgender-a-gender/)) and finally *gay* (never *gayed*).

Answer (score 1):

The Google Ngram in the original question is flawed. You must put parens around a term containing a hyphen. Try the search again using these terms: 
(full-size),(full-sized),full size,full sized

You will get a completely different result with 'full-sized' being by far the most common followed by 'full-size'.

Try this [corrected Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28full-size%29%2C%28full-sized%29%2Cfull+size%2Cfull+sized&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28full%20-%20size%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28full%20-%20sized%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfull%20size%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfull%20sized%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: This is incorrect.  The [ngram documentation](https://books.google.com/ngrams/info#) explains that parentheses are used to force it to be interpreted as a "composition"; it is doing some kind of subtraction of the terms "full" and "sized" rather than searching for "full-sized".

Answer (score 0):

I would use *full-size*. Compound adjectives preceding a noun should be hyphenated, unless the compound modifier includes something like *more, less, least,* etc.

Another pretty reliable test for hyphen necessity is to check whether the second element in your compound modifier can stand on its own.

In the case of 'full-size file', for instance, could we just have a 'size file'? 
In the case of 'full-sized' file, it seems to me that we could have a 'sized file,' but as shipr pointed out, this gives the impression that the file had the action of sizing applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

Logic (as adequately noted above) is on the side of *full-size*; usage is on the side of *full-sized*.

(Interestingly, the OED does not even list *size* as an adjective.)

The same logic speaks in favor of *age* instead of *aged* (They have one child, age three.) and *old fashion* instead of *old fashioned*.